# Problem when uploading php file

Tags: php, apache, upload

can anybody explain why uploaded php files treated by a server as a text file ?

The symptom is when i try to access a php file, the server send me the content of the file.

i have edited and put part of content as asked. **This is output i see in the browser**

> *** WHAT : Removinng Meta Box in Post using $pageshow thing WHY :*****************************************/function bk_cdp_meta_box($pageshow) { switch ($pageshow) { case 'postnew.php' : add_action('dbx_post_advanced', 'bk_cdp_meta_box_reindex'); break; case 'pagenew.php' : add_action('page_advanced', 'bk_cdp_meta_box_reindex'); break; default : } if ($pageshow != "") {// remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'post', 'normal');// remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', 'post', 'normal');// remove_meta_box('trackbacks', 'post', 'normal'); }}/**************************************** WHAT : Reindex List all of Post panel Metaboxes before get remove or add a new meta_box WHY : FIXME : TODO : RETURN : ARGs :***

**i download what i have upload and every one of them has <?php as i code it before**, so the source of problem exist somewhere else.

Comment: Does the server support php ? If yes, is Apache configured to handle php file ?

Comment: @Michael B and @bears, yes, the server support PHP. More over, it can execute previous uploaded file php. But not the new one.

Comment: post the code contained in the uploaded php file.

Comment: It's possible you don't have the *php open tag (`<?php`)* in your files. Any text outside that tag is echoed directly to the browser. Some servers also have the *short* open tag `<?` disabled. You may have difficulties if you use it.

Comment: @alexandre jasmis : nope. i use <?php, u i save the php file in  ascii mode in notepad++ (my coding editor).

Comment: @alexandre jasmin :  another information, i upload it on passive mode. 

The size of original file and the one that have been uploaded is different. and it's seem the uploaded file lost most of it's <br> or newline break

Comment: @justjoe Uploading in text mode (which has noting to do with passive mode) could cause DOS CRLF line endings to be replaced by Unix LF line endings. This would result in a small difference in file size. It shouldn't alter `<br>` tags though.

Comment: @Alexandre jasmin : so what should i do ? i understand your explanation except text mode's part. it's ascii or binary mode part ?

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin : i have make try to change every cr into crlf and it's successful. thank you very much to help me narrowing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen if your new uploaded files doesn't get executable attribute and the server is configured to prevent execution of such files. I've never seen such a thing though.

Answer (score 1):

If your code sample is from the start of your file the problem is you dont have any opening PHP tags e.g. `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the php open tags and the comment tags are wrong. Try this:

```
    <?php
    function bk_cdp_meta_box($pageshow) { 
           switch ($pageshow) { 
              case 'postnew.php' : 
              add_action('dbx_post_advanced', 'bk_cdp_meta_box_reindex'); 
              break; 

              case 'pagenew.php' : 
              add_action('page_advanced', 'bk_cdp_meta_box_reindex'); 
              break; 

              default : 
           } 
       if ($pageshow != "") {
      // remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'post', 'normal');
      // remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', 'post', 'normal');
      // remove_meta_box('trackbacks', 'post', 'normal'); 
     }
}

?>
```

Comment: @pixeline, the problem in not on that part.